# Can't get data to object

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

I'm trying to grap json data from mongodb, put it into a class objec and then print one parameter to console, but I get this error  :

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: O. Path '_id', line 1, position 10.'
```

My json looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d72b79c58011725b8b31b10"), "length" : NumberLong(957608), "
chunkSize" : 64512, "uploadDate" : ISODate("2019-09-06T19:46:42.058Z"), "md5" :
"3965979118e1302a7d19f609f38ede3e", "filename" : "C:\\Users\\kbu\\Downloads\\hve
m-er-vi.jpg", "metadata" : { "Beloeb" : "", "Overskrift" : "", "Gruppe" : "", "B
eskrivelse" : "", "Dato" : "6. september 2019", "Afsender" : "Lars" } }
```

I suspect, it has to do with my class, but I can't figure out what.

This is my code:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient("mongodb+srv://*********:*********@kbucluster-oslh9.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
            var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
            var collec = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("fs.files");

            var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty;
            var result = collec.Find(filter).ToList();

            foreach(var doc in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(doc.ToJson());

                RootObject bilag = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(doc.ToJson());

                Console.WriteLine(bilag.ID);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Metadata
    {
        public string Beloeb { get; set; }
        public string Overskrift { get; set; }
        public string Gruppe { get; set; }
        public string Beskrivelse { get; set; }
        public string Dato { get; set; }
        public string Afsender { get; set; }
    }
    public class RootObject
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Length { get; set; }
        public string ChunkSize { get; set; }
        public string UploadDate { get; set; }
        public string MD5 { get; set; }
        public string Filename { get; set; }
        public Metadata Metadata { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need json.net if you match the property names/types of the RootObject like this:

```cs
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class Metadata
        {
            public string Beloeb { get; set; }
            public string Overskrift { get; set; }
            public string Gruppe { get; set; }
            public string Beskrivelse { get; set; }
            public string Dato { get; set; }
            public string Afsender { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            [BsonId] // need to add this
            public ObjectId ID { get; set; }
            public int length { get; set; }
            public double chunkSize { get; set; }
            public DateTime uploadDate { get; set; }
            public string md5 { get; set; }
            public string filename { get; set; }
            public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var collection = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")
                                    .GetDatabase("test")
                                    .GetCollection<RootObject>("fs.files");

            var result = collection.Find(Builders<RootObject>.Filter.Empty).ToList();

            foreach (var doc in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(doc.ToJson());
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine(doc.ID.ToString());
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method

```
object dotnetObject = BsonTypeMapper.MapToDotNetValue(bsonDocument);

// Json mapped to default .Net objects
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dotnetObject);

// Parsing as JObject
var jobject = JObject.Parse(json);

// Deserializing as your custom Type
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have functions in your JSON

```
"_id" :ObjectId("5d72b79c58011725b8b31b10"), "length" : NumberLong(957608),"uploadDate" : ISODate("2019-09-06T19:46:42.058Z")
```

```
Parse error on line 1:
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d72b79c58
----------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 0):

1-Wrong value _id key : "what is ObjectId method in json"?

2-wrong name _id : beacause in `RootObject` class ,property is `ID`!

3- you must remove `ObjectId` , `NumberLong` , `ISODate` With their braces

```
{ "ID" : "5d72b79c58011725b8b31b10", "Length" : "957608", "
ChunkSize" : "64512", "UploadDate" : "2019-09-06T19:46:42.058Z", "MD5" :
"3965979118e1302a7d19f609f38ede3e", "FileName" : "C:\\Users\\kbu\\Downloads\\hve
m-er-vi.jpg", "Metadata" : { "Beloeb" : "", "Overskrift" : "", "Gruppe" : "", "B
eskrivelse" : "", "Dato" : "6. september 2019", "Afsender" : "Lars" } }
```